# Exibir elementos de array sem a chave

Tags: php, html, array, session

Olá, estou com um pequeno "problema". Estou tentando iterar uma sessão de array através de um foreach, porém sempre devolve apenas um resultado. Então utilizei um var_dump() e o resultado foi isso:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Por favor, informe um CNPJ válido.' (length=35)
      1 => string 'Por favor, informe um telefone válido.' (length=39)
      2 => string 'Por favor, informe um celular válido.' (length=38)
```

Para fazer adicionar elementos no array, estou utilizando o array_push() e para a exibição usei este loop:

```
foreach($_SESSION['msg_cadastro_erro'] as $key => $value) {
     echo $value[$key];
}
```

O código:

```
<?php
include('conexao.php');

session_start();

$erro = false;
$msg_erro = array();

function anti_sql_injection($string)
{
    include('conexao.php');
    $string = stripslashes($string);
    $string = strip_tags($string);
    $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $string);
    return $string;
}

if (isset($_POST['salvar_cliente'])) {

    if (isset($_POST['cliente']) && !empty($_POST['cliente'])) {
        $cliente = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['cliente']));
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe um cliente.");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['fantasia']) && !empty($_POST['cliente'])) {
        $fantasia = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['fantasia']));
    } else {
        $fantasia = "";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['cnpj']) && !empty($_POST['cnpj'])) {
        $cnpj = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['cnpj']));
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe um CNPJ válido.");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['ie']) && !empty($_POST['cliente'])) {
        $ie = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['ie']));
    } else {
        $ie = "";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['rua']) && !empty($_POST['rua'])) {
        $rua = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['rua']));
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe uma rua válida");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['numero']) && !empty($_POST['numero'])) {
        $numero = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['numero']));
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe um número válido.");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['bairro']) && !empty($_POST['bairro'])) {
        $bairro = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['bairro']));
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe um bairro válido.");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['estado']) && !empty($_POST['estado'])) {
        $estado = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['estado']));
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe um estado válido.");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['cidade']) && !empty($_POST['cidade'])) {
        $cidade = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['cidade']));
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe uma cidade válida.");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['cep']) && !empty($_POST['cep'])) {
        $cep = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['cep']));
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe um CEP válido.");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['uf']) && !empty($_POST['uf'])) {
        $uf = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['uf']));
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe uma UF válida.");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['telefone']) && !empty($_POST['telefone'])) {
        $telefone = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['telefone']));
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe um telefone válido.");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['celular']) && !empty($_POST['celular'])) {
        $celular = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['celular']));
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe um celular válido.");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $v_email = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['email']));
        if(filter_var($v_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $email = $v_email;
        } else {
            $erro = true;
            array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe um e-mail válido.");
        }
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe um e-mail válido.");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['senha']) && !empty($_POST['senha'])) {
        $senha = anti_sql_injection(($_POST['senha']));
    } else {
        $erro = true;
        array_push($msg_erro, "Por favor, informe uma cidade válida.");
    }

    if (!$erro) {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (cnpj, ie, cliente, fantasia, rua, numero, bairro, estado, cidade, uf, cep, telefone, celular, email, senha) VALUES ('$cnpj', '$ie', '$cliente', '$fantasia', '$rua', '$numero', '$bairro', '$estado', '$cidade', '$uf', '$cep', '$telefone', '$celular', '$email', '$senha')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if ($result) {
            $_SESSION['msg_cadastro_sucesso'] = "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso";
            header("Location: ../painel/clientes.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['msg_cadastro_erro'] = "Ocorreu um erro inexperado. Contate o desenvolvedor." .mysqli_error($conn);
            header("Location: ../painel/clientes.php");
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['msg_cadastro_erro'][] = $msg_erro;
        header("Location: ../painel/clientes.php");
    }
```

Comment: Parece que você construiu o array diferente do que pretendia. O que você quer iterar é `$_SESSION['msg_cadastro_erro'][0]`, mas será melhor corrigir a forma que monta o array e deixá-lo da forma desejada.

Comment: Para montar o array eu declarei da seguinte forma `$msg_erro = array()` e para incluir novos elementos `array_push($msg_erro, "string qualquer");`. Tenho absoluta certeza que estou errando em algum ponto, mas não identifiquei qual.

Comment: Então coloque o código na pergunta que nós te ajudamos.

Comment: `$_SESSION['msg_cadastro_erro'][] = $msg_erro`, por que esses colchetes `[]`?

Comment: Só uma dica: a variável `$erro` é desnecessária. Sempre que você faz um `array_push` você faz `$erro = true`. No final das contas o valor de `$erro` vai ser sempre o mesmo que `count($msg_erro) > 0`, ou como no PHP um array vazio é _falsy_ você poderia substituir `if (!erro)` por `if ($msg_erro)`.

Comment: E na [documentação do `array_push`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php) diz que é a mesma coisa que executar `$array[] = $x;`. Então eu usaria `array_push` somente se tiver que adicionar mais de um elementos ao mesmo tempo no array, assim evitaria uma chamada de função desnecessária.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Era exatamente isso. Removi os colchetes e corrigi o foreach e já funcionou como eu desejava. Obrigado! @fernandosavio Sim! Eu já tinha consultado a documentação do PHP, anteriormente o meu código estava usando `$array[]`, porém nas minhas tentativas de arrumar o código, acabei alterando. Valeu!

Comment: Ah, @fernandosavio obrigado pelas dicas, estarei fazendo essas correções!

Comment: Opa, lembrando que trocar `array_push` por `$arr[] = $x` trás benefícios, mas é puramente uma questão de opinião. :D